# Hyperlinking theorems in smfart

Tags: hyperref, theorems, debugging

**Edit:** The class `smfart` is one of several classes created by the [Société Mathématique  de France](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Formats/) for typesetting mathematics. [Here is its CTAN page](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/smflatex), where it lies under `smflatex`, and [here is the documentation](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Formats/e-doc.pdf).

Briefly put, **the class `smfart`, when combined with `hyperref`, does not properly link to the theorem environment**.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[english]{smfart}
\usepackage[francais,english]{babel}
\usepackage{smfthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\begin{theo}\label{thetheorem}
d
\end{theo}

Consider \ref{thetheorem}

\end{document}
```

I compile by running `pdflatex` on the file twice. The second time, you get the following error message:

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{smfthm.0.1} ha
s been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

It is not difficult to check that the hyperlink which *should* link to the theorem actually links to the very beginning of the document.

What is going on here? Is there a known way to fix this?

Comment: Since `smfart` is not a known class, it might be an idea to provide a link to where one can get this (it is not listed on CTAN).

Comment: The problem seems to lie in the fact that `smfart` loads `amsthm` but also modifies the meaning of several commands of this package, while `hyperref` works under the assumption that these commands are not redefined.

Answer (score 2):

The `smfart` class changes the definitions related to new theorems, after loading `amsthm`, in particular `\@begintheorem`.

Now `hyperref` sees that `amsthm` is loaded and so hooks in `\@begintheorem` expecting it to be the same as provided by the package, but it is not. Conflict ensues.

Since `smfart` and the other similar classes are not on CTAN it is very unlikely that Heiko Oberdiek takes action for coping with it. This is a job for the developers of the class, if they want to support `hyperref` in their documents.

Comment: Hi, do you know if there is some "hack" we can use to fix this problem while we wait for the class developers to solve the issue?

Comment: @vap Sorry, no.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a `\phantomsection` before `\label{bla}` fixes this issue. See also [here](http://fr.comp.text.tex.narkive.com/yPKyQbKk/mauvais-referencement-avec-hyperref).

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the observation of egreg, I've compared the files `smfart.cls` and `amsthm.sty`. It seems that there are two crucial lines in the `amsth.sty` version of `\@begintheorem` which are missing in the `smfart.cls` version, namely

```
\global\@inlabeltrue
\everypar\dth@everypar
```

Adding these two lines into the definition of `\@begintheorem` in `smfart.cls` seems to resolve the problem. 
Here is an example of modification:

```
\def\@begintheorem#1#2[#3]{%
  \def\@theoremhead{\normalfont\the\thm@headfont
    \@ifempty{#1}{\let\thmname\@gobble}{\let\thmname\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#2}{\let\thmnumber\@gobble}{\let\thmnumber\@iden}%
    \@ifempty{#3}{\let\thmnote\@gobble}{\let\thmnote\@iden}%
  \thm@swap\swappedhead\thmhead{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\@theoremhead}%
  \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>0.7\linewidth \smf@skippttrue\fi
  \ifsmf@skippt
  \global\smf@skipptfalse
  \item [\thm@indent]%
    {\sloppy\@theoremhead\parskip\z@\@@par}%
  \nobreak\everypar{}%
  \let\thmheadnl\relax
  \else
  \item[\hskip\labelsep\thm@indent\unhbox\@tempboxa\the\thm@headpunct]%
  %%    \hskip\z@\ignorespaces
  \fi
  \@restorelabelsep
  \thmheadnl % possibly a newline.
   \global\@inlabeltrue   %the two lines 
   \everypar\dth@everypar %borrowed from amsthm
  \ignorespaces}
```

I would be happy if anyone can kindly explain the meaning of these two lines.